# How to draw Jqplot into HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jqplot

Can anyone say how to draw jqplot in to HTML canvas element?
I tried this,

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var imgData = $('#jqplot').jqplotToImageStr({});

var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgData);
$('#imgChart1').append(imgElem);

var img=document.getElementById("imgChart1");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

It didn't work . Is there any wrong method? can anyone help me please ?

Comment: jqplot library already uses canvas elements. why r u trying to specify the canvas elements? any specific reason behind it.

Comment: @Gyandeep I want to download jqplot chart as a image by button click or click on link. If I put the jqplot into a canvas I think I can do it. Can you help me? In this way or any kind of idea is accepted to download.

Answer (score 0):

just create the jqplot graph using the API by supplying the ID of a `div` element. Later you can call `jqplotToImageStr` on the same div ID. It will generate the image for you.
Eg:

```
var imageData = $('#chart_div').jqplotToImageStr({});
var copyImage = $('<img/>').attr('src', imageData);
$('#copy-container').html(copyImage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but my ultimate goal is to download the image by a button click or click on a link. Saving this to another div as a image doesn't solve my problem.Have you any idea how to do that?

Comment: As per the top example, `imageData` is what you want to save. that is the image. have you tried it.

Comment: How to save image data ? Can you please tell me? Can it be done by a button click or LINK?